# Javascript fetch doesn't return despite correct URL

Tags: javascript

I've used JQuery in the past to do AJAX requests. I am trying to now use `fetch` and I am struggling.

My code is very simple, and it calls a C# backend. The back end break point is hit, so I don't believe there is any issue with the URL

```
this.get = function (url) {
    return getData(url);
};

async function getData(url = '') {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'same-origin', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', 
        credentials: 'same-origin', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        redirect: 'follow', 
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'      
    });

    return await response.json(); // BREAK POINT NEVER HIT
}
```

In the browsers dev tools, I put a break point at the line `const response = await fetch(url, {` and another on the `return await response.json;`

The first break is hit. The second never hits. I don't see any error message or exception.

How do I find out what is going on?

Looking at the response, it shows it's pending a promise

[image]

**EDIT**

It seems as if my program is not waiting with `await`... My understanding is the code should not progress until it has received (waited) for a response. What is happening is, as soon as it hits the `await`, it seems to exit the function. The breakpoint on `return await response.json()` does eventually get hit, but `await` is acting like a new thread.

Comment: What if you point it at a URL which isn't your own backend? https://www.mocky.io/

Comment: Exactly the same @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 2):

[response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) returns a promise, not the content. So you will need to `return await response.json()`

Also, your server should return the data with the content-type being set to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: Sadly, even with this change, it still never hits the "return" line's breakpoint :(

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions May you share any logs from the fetch output?

Answer (score 1):

Well I do get a `response` when a try with a mock url:
http://jsfiddle.net/0zavw15j/

```js
getData('https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits');
async function getData(url = '') {
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', 
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'      
});
   let commits = await response.json(); // read response body and parse as JSON

alert(commits);// <---- this is hitting
}
```

Comment: Yours is slightly different I *think*. I have an await in the response. So, try  `alert(await response.json());` It does not hit

Comment: Actually this mock url I was using was returning a promise do I had to comment that out.

Comment: I copied and pasted this into my site. It still doesn't hit the break point so I guess something very odd is going on with my machine......When I look at the return object though, it always shows `Promise<pending>`

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions yeah `Promise<pending>` is because of this mock url not correctly giving a response properly. You may try with a different url

Comment: can you put your `await` in a variable and return that just like I have done?
`let commits = await response.json(); return commits`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there is no response (either 200 as positive or any error status code like 404, 500), this means that there was no response at all. Happens sometimes because request goes in an infinite loop of redirects or really long loop of redirects.

I suggest trying request without redirect set to "follow", like this

```
async function getData(url = '') {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'same-origin', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', 
        credentials: 'same-origin', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'      
    });

    return response.json(); // BREAK POINT NEVER HIT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, I returning a promise, so everything was not synchronous...

As soon as I changed it to

```
async function getData (url = '', successCallback){
    ….
    success(await response.json());
}
```

it worked fine